# update table with row_number based on two columns

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
id      country         date
----------------------------------
1         4             2022-05-01
1         4             2022-06-01
1         4             2022-07-01
1         5             2022-05-01
1         5             2022-06-01
2         5             2022-06-01
```

I want this, the `row_number` based on id and country.

I have this table

```
id      country         date               row_number
------------------------------------------------------
1         4             2022-05-01             1
1         4             2022-06-01             2
1         4             2022-07-01             3
1         5             2022-05-01             1
1         5             2022-06-01             2
2         5             2022-06-01             1
```

I am doing this but it not working:

```
UPDATE table
SET row_number = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM [pay].[f_lending_net_margin] AS f
                  WHERE country = f.country AND id = f.id);
```

Here I got he same value for all records

Second attempt:

```
UPDATE table
SET row_number = x.row_num
FROM [pay].[f_lending_net_margin] AS f
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         country, id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country, id ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num 
     FROM table) AS x ON x.country = f.country AND x.id = f.id
```

But this is duplicating data.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be over-complicating things - assuming you have the column `[row_number]` already on the table, you can use an updatable table expression:

```
update t set t.[row_number] = rn
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by Id, Country order by date) rn
    from t
)t;
```

See a [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gZNIjgbG)